# Testing Actions, Reducers, & Contexts in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-context, react-testing-library

I've built multiple React functional components using Hooks and Context.  Everything works fine.  Now I need to write tests for everything.  I'm confused about how to move forward with some of them so wanted to reach out to the community.

**Actions**
Here's a sampling from one of my Actions files:

```
export const ADD_VEHICLE: 'ADD_VEHICLE' = 'ADD_VEHICLE';
export const UPDATE_VEHICLE: 'UPDATE_VEHICLE' = 'UPDATE_VEHICLE';

type AddVehicleAction = {type: typeof ADD_VEHICLE, isDirty: boolean};
type UpdateVehicleAction = {type: typeof UPDATE_VEHICLE, id: number, propName: string, payload: string | number};

export type VehiclesActions = 
     | AddVehicleAction
     | UpdateVehicleAction;
```

How am I supposed to test this Actions file?  I don't mean in conjunction with anything else, I mean it and only it?
*From the comments, it appears I have agreement that there's nothing to test DIRECTLY in this file.*

**Reducers**
Each of my Reducers files is directly connected to and supports a specific Context.  Here's a sampling of one of my Reducers files:

```
import type { VehiclesState } from '../VehiclesContext';
import type { VehiclesActions } from '../actions/Vehicles';
import type { Vehicle } from '../SharedTypes';

import { ADD_VEHICLE,
         UPDATE_VEHICLE
       } from '../actions/Vehicles';

export const vehiclesReducer = (state: VehiclesState, action: VehiclesActions) => {
  switch (action.type) {

  case ADD_VEHICLE: {
    const length = state.vehicles.length;
    const newId = (length === 0) ? 0 : state.vehicles[length - 1].id + 1;
    const newVehicle = {
      id: newId,
      vin: '',
      license: ''
    };

    return {
      ...state,
      vehicles: [...state.vehicles, newVehicle],
      isDirty: action.isDirty
    };
  }

  case UPDATE_VEHICLE: {
    return {
      ...state,
      vehicles: state.vehicles.map((vehicle: Vehicle) => {
        if (vehicle.id === action.id) {
          return {
            ...vehicle,
            [action.propName]: action.payload
          };
        } else {
          return vehicle;
        }
      }),
      isDirty: true
    };
  }
```

If you wanted to build tests for JUST this Reducers file, what approach would you use?  My thought was to render the DOM like this:

```
function CustomComponent() {
  const vehiclesState = useVehiclesState();
  const { isDirty,
          companyId,
          vehicles 
        } = vehiclesState;  
  const dispatch = useVehiclesDispatch();

  return null;
}

function renderDom() {
  return {
    ...render(
      <VehiclesProvider>
        <CustomComponent />
      </VehiclesProvider>
    )  
  };
}
```

While this code above does run, I now have the problem that both `vehiclesState` and `dispatch` are not accessible within my test code so I'm trying to figure out how to "surface" those within each `describe / it` construct.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Contexts**
My Contexts follow the same pattern outlined by Kent C. Dodds: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively - in that the StateContext & DispatchContext are separated, and there's a default state.  Given this code pattern and given that I'll already have a separate test file for the Context's Reducers, what specifically could one test for ONLY for the Context?

Comment: That feels way too broad! Also, this depends on what you want to test and then the implementation is primarily opinion based.

Comment: It is really not clear what you're asking. The code you posted above, it's just type declaration, there's nothing to test. You may want to update your post with a more defined question

Comment: @EmileBergeron Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I've updated the question as per your feedback.  For starters, I believe I have your agreement that testing the Actions files is impossible/unnecessary.  How would you go about testing a Reducers file such as the one I've outlined.  And would testing the Context (with analogous code to Kent C. Dodds) be unnecessary because the essentials of everything is performed when testing the Reducer?

Comment: Have you read redux docs on writing tests? https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests this is probably a good start for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as my comment, I really think you should read [redux docs for writing tests](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests) so that you get a general idea of what to do.

But since you already have a reducer, you want to write your test case to follow this pattern

1. you will have at least 1 test per action
2. each test will have a a "previous state", which will be altered
3. you will call your reducer, passing the action and the previous state
4. you will assert your new state is the same as expected

Here's a code example:

```
it('adds a new car when there are no cars yet', () => {
  // you want to put here values that WILL change, so that you don't risk
  // a false positive in your unit test
  const previousState = {
    vehicles: [],
    isDirty: false,
  };

  const state = reducer(previousState, { type: ADD_VEHICLE });

  expect(state).toEqual({
    vehicles: [{
      id: 1,
      vin: '',
      license: '',
    }],
    isDirty: true,
  });
});

it('adds a new car when there are existing cars already, () => {
  // ...
});
```

I'd also recommend to use action creators rather than directly creating action objects, since it's more readable:

```
// actions.js
export const addVehicle = () => ({
  type: ADD_VEHICLE
})

// reducer.test.js
it('adds a new car when there are no cars yet', () => {
  //...
  const state = reducer(previousState, actions.addVehicle());
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I will read the document you referred me to right now.